# Vscode suggestions/intellisense big window/modal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I wanna disable this popup option but dont know where in the vscode settings. I try a lot but no success so far:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to disable intellisense in its entirety?

Comment: at least for the css part, the modal/window covers the cursor or the line before.

Comment: Looks like some others feel your pain too https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/33752

Comment: Thank you. your link has the answer. Just disabled in Editor > Parameter hints enabled.

Comment: Feel free to add the specific part as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Just disabled in settings

*Editor > Parameter hints enabled*

Comment: Whoever -1'd this, it's acceptable for an OP to post an answer if they find it first.